# Javascript/JQuery split paragraph to get a single word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split

I'm working on trying to split the text of a paragraph using javascript/jQuery to get a specific word. The HTML looks something like this:

```
<p class="overview">
   Last Name:
   Blah blah blah
   Derp dee derp:
   <br>
   Last Name: Davis
   <br>
   First Name: Jerry     
</p>
```

I'm trying to extract just the last name (Davis) and save it to a variable, but I cannot figure out how to do it using the javascript .split() method. Right now I'm doing something that I'm sure is so wrong. I don't even want to share it, but here it is.

```
var splitS = ($("p.overview").text().split(["First Name:", "Last Name:"], 3));
```

Obviously I do not have a very good grasp on this method and I haven't been able to find anything in my searches that proved to be helpful. Thanks

Edited: Typo ("class="). Also I forgot it's a little more complex than I originally posted. There are more than one occurrence of the string "Last Name:" and there is a break right before and after the last name I'm trying to get out of the p element.

Comment: Quick typo, `class="overview"`

Comment: Oy, thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it would be easier with a regex, if the labels (`Last Name:`  etc) are always the same

```js
var txt = $('.overview').text();

var lastName = txt.match(/Last Name: (.*)/)[1];

alert(lastName)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="overview">
   Last Name:
   Blah blah blah
   Derp dee derp:
   <br>
   Last Name: Davis
   <br>
   First Name: Jerry     
</p>
```

Comment: Sorry, I really screwed my original post. Would you mind looking at the html edit again? I forgot it was a little more complex than I had originally written it.

Comment: @DjH - the breaks shouldn't matter, as long as the string `Last Name: ` is the same

Comment: @ardeno , thanks. It's working in actual use but giving me everything that follows "Last Name:" as well. So the value of lastName is coming back as "DavisFirst Name: Jerry"

Comment: Ok, I ended up adding a split() to it and now it is returning just the last name. So the working code is      txt.match(/Last Name: (.*)/)[1].split("First Name: ", 1);